# Jquery Dialog Error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have Imported all **.js** files and UI files needed to run this function...
When i am executing this code using Google CDN its works fine. But when i try running using same CDN files as .js files inside the project it throws error `cancel is not a function..`

```
 $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 250,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,        

      buttons: {
          "Buy Now": function() {         
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );        
              var folionumber=$("#folionum").val();
              //---------------code change--------
              var firsturl = "https://www.sbimf.com/INVESTORCENTER/ASPX/frmNew_Purchase.aspx?id=";
              var id=1;
              var calledfrom = "&calledfrom=asset&fol_no=" + folionumber + "&chk_digit=&opt=B&SchemeCode=" + schemecode + "&url=" + encurl;

              var finalurl=firsturl+id+calledfrom;

              // alert(finalurl);
              window.open(finalurl, "_parent");      
              // window.open("http://172.24.10.203/INVESTORCENTER/ASPX/frmNew_Purchase.aspx?id=1&calledfrom=PortFolio&fol_no=13627577&chk_digit=&opt=B&SchemeCode=D018");    
          },
          Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
      },    

      open: function () {
          $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").addClass("dialog_style1");
          $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("titlebar");
          $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").addClass("dialog_style1");
          $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").find(".ui-dialog-buttonset").find(".ui-button").find(".ui-button-text").addClass("btncss");
          $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").addClass("smallbutton"); 

      }
 });
```

Comment: So, how you are including those `.js` files

Comment: Make sure that you're including `.js` files in the correct order (jquery, jqueryui, css files)

Answer (score 0):

my issue is solved. I have linked older JS Files.I replaced it with new JS its working smooth now